# How to pass null in SQL IN Clause through ado.net query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, ado.net

I am passing a list of employee IDs to my ado.net query. Sometimes my list is empty so I am getting error on this condition.

The error saying: `Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Here is my code:

```
var emps = String.Join(",", empList.Keys);
            StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(
                $@"select [Id]
                FROM [Test].[dbo].[Employees]
                Where [Id] NOT IN {emps}"
                );
```

Comment: You're using string interpolation to construct a dynamic SQL string, not passing anything. Don't do that. Imagine what would happen if one of the values was `) or 1=1;--`. Your query will *always* fail because the ID list isn't enclosed in parentheses. You can't have an empty `IN` clause either, so if the list is empty you shouldn't add the condition

Comment: @haldo sorry! this is not an issue. I corrected the mistake in the question

Comment: @SagharFrancis people already answered the question. You can't use that condition if `emps` is empty. You'll have to add the condition only if `emps` contains data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but I am getting data after building the query. and I am getting while building the query

Comment: `but I am getting data after building the data. and I am getting while building the query` that phrase makes no sense. What do you want to do if the list is empty? Return all rows or none? If that's your actual query why not just check the contents and use a *different* query each time? Does your query have more conditions ?  [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) for example will emit `IN (SELECT NULL WHERE 1 = 0)` which most databases will handle as a no-op for an empty set. This allows combining `IN` with other clauses without generating different queries

Comment: Nothing in your posted code appears to generate the required `( )` around the IN set; the formed SQL will always have a syntax error

Comment: Plenty of problems in that SQL you posted, but you appear to be saying you will run this SQL over and over again, each time adding more IDs to exclude. Perhaps you do something that constantly discovers new IDs that should be ignored? It would be significantly easier for you if you could make that thing a column in the database, like `SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE status <> 'Shipped'` and then set the ones you want to ignore to "Shipped". If you really must keep an ever growing list of IDs to exclude, keep them as SqlParameters, keep a stub SQL that you add parameter names to

Comment: You can make life easier by putting a value in that will never occur naturally, so you always have at least 1 item in your NOT IN and you don't need to toggle the presence/absence of it. You cannot meaningfully use NULL in a NOT IN though; `2 NOT IN (NULL, 1)` is eventually false, and there is no value you can swap for the 2 that produces a true

Comment: You are currently in danger of SQL injection, as you are injecting the values directly into the query. If you are just fetching them only to pass them back, why don't you just keep the whole dataset on the server? You could perhaps use joins? Also, consider using a Table Valued Parameter to pass the whole set in one go, this will be more performant than sending many separate variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your emp list beforehand and only add the WHERE clause to the StringBuilder if the list in not empty.
ALSO there is an extra ')' in your sql string,

Where [Id] NOT IN {emps}*)*

You need to remove it.

Comment: If I do this every time it will pass null in the query because after the query I am fetching the records from DB and appending in the list.

Comment: @SagharFrancis `If I do this every time it will pass null in the query` no it won't. `select [Id]
 FROM [Test].[dbo].[Employees]` works fine. You can't have an empty `IN` clause, period.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of problems in that SQL you posted, but you appear to be saying you will run this SQL over and over again, each time adding more IDs to exclude. Perhaps you do something that constantly discovers new IDs that should be ignored

Consider:

```
using var con = new SqlConnection(...);

for(..some..ongoing..iterative..process){

    empList = ..get new IDs here..

    var sql = "select [Id] from [Test].[dbo].[Employees] ";
    if(empList.Count > 0){
      sql += $"where [Id] NOT IN ({string.Join(",", empList.Select((kvp,i) => $"@p{i}"))})";
    }

    using var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

    //it's a no-op if 0 values
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(empList.Select((kvp,i) => new SqlParameter($"@p{i}", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = kvp.Value }));

    ..execute here..
}
```

Where you open and close your `con` rather depends on how long it takes to work out your new ids. If it's a few milliseconds each time, it shouldn't be a problem to open it before the loop. If getting new IDs takes long, open the con for just the time you need it